# BufferedInputStream is not taking large input

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I am relatively new in java and I am trying to take a binary matrix as input, where total number of rows & columns will be between 2 & 1000. I am using BufferedInputStream, and for small matrix my code is working (giving right output) for example a 4x4 matrix. But for a 6x9 input it is not working. Actually I'm trying to solve UVA problem no 12367.

My code

```
 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 class Main {
    static int totalOne=0;

    public static int swapCount(int array[]) {
        int L = array.length, s=0;
        for (int n=0;n<L;n++) {                     
            int avg = totalOne / L;
            if (array[n]>avg) {
                int x=1;    
                while (array[n]>avg) {
                    int t = n+x;
                    int u = n-x;

                    if (t>L-1) {
                        if (array[t-L]<avg) {                           
                                array[n]--;
                                array[t-L]++;
                                s++;                            
                        }
                    }   
                    else {
                        if (array[t]<avg) {                         
                            array[n]--;
                            array[t]++;
                            s++;                            
                        } 
                    }

                    if (array[n]>avg) { 
                        if (u<0) {
                            if (array[u+L]<avg) {                           
                                        array[n]--;
                                        array[u+L]++;
                                        s++;                            
                                }
                        }
                        else {
                                if (array[u]<avg) {                         
                                    array[n]--;
                                    array[u]++;
                                    s++;                            
                                } 
                        }
                    }
                }
                x++;
            }       
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));

            int t = stdin.nextInt();
            int a,b,i=0,flag=0,swap=0;
            String result = new String();
            if (t<=10) {
                while (i<t) {
                    i++;
                    totalOne = 0;
                    int R = stdin.nextInt();
                    int C = stdin.nextInt();
                    int [][] arr = new int [R][C];
                    int [] rowOne= new int [R];
                    int [] colOne= new int [C];
                    if (2<=R&&2<=C&&R<=1000&&C<=1000)  {
                        for (a=0;a<R;a++) {
                            for (b=0;b<C;b++) {
                                arr[a][b]=stdin.nextInt();
                                if (arr[a][b]!=0 && arr[a][b]!=1)
                                    flag=1;
                                if (arr[a][b]==1){
                                    rowOne[a]++;
                                    colOne[b]++;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (flag==0) {
                            for (a=0;a<R;a++)
                            totalOne=totalOne+rowOne[a];
                            if (totalOne%R==0) {
                                result = "row";
                                swap = swapCount(rowOne);
                                if (totalOne%C==0) {
                                    result = "both";
                                    swap = swap + swapCount(colOne);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if (totalOne%C==0) {
                                    result = "column";
                                    swap = swapCount(colOne);
                                }
                                else {
                                    result = "impossible";
                                }
                            }               


                            if (result.equals("impossible")) 
                                System.out.println("Case "+i+": "+result);  
                            else {  
                                System.out.println("Case "+i+": "+result+" "+swap);
                            }                       

                        }   
                    }
            }
        }
       System.exit(0);
    }
 }
```

For input like this:

```
1
4 4
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
```

(Where 1 is number of test case, 4 4 is matrix dimensions & rest are matrix elements)

Output is "Case 1: both 4" which is expected but for input like below-

```
1
6 9
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

it doesn't give any output & when debuggging I found that before reading all the matrix elements, it is stepping from the main thread therefore the program is not executing.

Can anyone tell me where is the problem :( is it related with buffer size?

Comment: Do you mean *BufferedInputStream?*

Comment: Your program does not block on input; it enters an infinite loop. Nothing to do with the input stream.

Comment: Well, it can enter into an infinite loop but isn't it supposed to read all the inputs first? But while debugging, I saw the Main thread is stepping even before it read all the input..

Comment: Found my mistake.. sorry for the lame question :(